# Automatically making taxonomy terms children

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Im using a taxonomy system that basically uses one long tag to describe items,
for instance apple-butter-cherries would be one term

Is it possible to make the term apple-butter a child of apple-butter-cherries upon creation?